# Is there an idiomatic way to count a subset of array elements in Polymer?

Tags: arrays, polymer, idioms

I have a model with an array of objects. The objects have a property the user can update.

In another part of the UI, I would like to show some statistics about the array; the total number of items and the number of items having the property set.

An example with one-arrays instead of objects. Click a list item to toggle the "a" property: http://jsfiddle.net/rskqbquL/4/

```
<polymer-element name="test-cool">
    <template>
        <ol>
            <template repeat="{{item, i in list}}">
                <li on-tap="{{onTap}}" x-index="{{i}}">{{item[0]}}</li>
            </template>
        </ol>
        <p>Total: {{list.length}}</p>
        <p>A:s: {{list | countA}}</p>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer("test-cool", {
            list: [["a"], ["ab"], ["ac"], ["d"], ["e"]],

            countA: function(list) {
                var ret = 0;

                list.forEach(function(item) {
                    if (item[0].indexOf("a") >= 0) ++ret;
                });
                return ret;
            },
            onTap: function(e, _, el) {
                var item = el.innerText;
                var index = parseInt(el.getAttribute("x-index"));

                if (item.indexOf("a") >= 0) {
                    this.list[index][0] = item.slice(1);
                } else {
                    this.list[index][0] = "a" + item;
                }

                // Workaround
                this.list = this.list.slice();
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>

<test-cool></test-cool>
```

I cannot find any way to observe a specific property of all items of an array, hence the workaround dummy assignment of the list in onTap().

What is the idiomatic Polymer way of gathering statistics about array subsets?

Answer (score 0):

Using a filter and tickling the `list` (e.g. 1this.list = this.list.slice()`) works, but every time the`on-tap`handlers gets called, the entire DOM list is rendered. Instead, I would create a`counterA` variable to keep track of the array length.

Also, instead of using:

```
var item = el.innerText;
var index = parseInt(el.getAttribute("x-index"));
```

you can use the data model directly ([docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#templateinstancemodel)):

```
var item = el.templateInstance.model.item;
var index = el.templateInstance.model.i;
```

One way to approach this is something like http://jsbin.com/fitav/1/edit:

```
<p>A:s: {{countA}}</p>

onTap: function(e, detail, el) {
    var item = el.templateInstance.model.item;
    var index = el.templateInstance.model.i;

    this.list[index][0] = this.hasA(item[0])  ? 
                          item[0].slice(1) : "a" + item;

    this.countA = this.filterA();
},
hasA: function(item) {
  return item.indexOf("a") >= 0;
},
listChanged: function() {
  this.countA = this.filterA();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The current best practice is to use an *observation kick* to trigger the recalculation. Fwiw, we're generally not happy with this answer, and are working on better automation.

The gambit is to describe your binding like so:

```
    <p>A:s: {{list | countA(kick)}}</p>
```

and at the critical place where the list items are being changed, increment the `kick` property. To be clear, the `kick` property serves no purpose other than to trigger the recalculation.

```
    kick: 0,
    onTap: function(e) {
      var item = e.target.templateInstance.model.item;
      item[0] = this.toggleA(item[0]);
      this.kick++;
    }
```

As I said, this is a temporary solution until we work out more automated change detection or at least provide an api for kicking.

Full implementation here: http://jsbin.com/naboke/5/edit

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a Polymer element that I recently wrote for this purpose: [`<observe-array-items>`](https://github.com/jeffposnick/observe-array-items). `<observe-array-items>` simplifies the process of creating/maintaining [`PathObserver`](https://github.com/polymer/observe-js#pathobserver)s for each of the items in an array.

```html
<script src="//www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="//rawgit.com/jeffposnick/observe-array-items/master/observe-array-items.html">

<polymer-element name="array-observation">
  <template>
    <observe-array-items array="{{list}}"
                 path="text"
                 on-array-item-changed="{{handleArrayItemChanged}}">
    </observe-array-items>
    
    <ol>
      <template repeat="{{item in list}}">
        <li on-tap="{{handleListTap}}">{{item.text}}</li>
      </template>
    </ol>
    
    <p>
      <input type="text" value="{{newItemText}}">
      <button on-tap="{{handleAddItem}}">Add Item</button>
    </p>

    <p>Total: {{list.length}}</p>
    <p>'A's: {{countOfA}}</p>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      countOfA: 0,
      list: null,
      newItemText: 'f',
      
      listChanged: function() {
        // This will be triggered when list is first initialized,
        // and any time an item is added or removed from the array.
        var count = 0;
        
        this.list.forEach(function(item) {
          if (this._hasA(item.text)) {
            count++;
          }
        }.bind(this));
        
        this.countOfA = count;
      },
      
      _hasA: function(str) {
        console.log('checking', str);
        return str.indexOf('a') >= 0;
      },
      
      handleArrayItemChanged: function(e) {
        if (!this._hasA(e.detail.oldValue) && this._hasA(e.detail.newValue)) {
          // If the old value didn't have an 'a' and the new value does, then increment countOfA.
          this.countOfA++;
        } else if(this._hasA(e.detail.oldValue) && !this._hasA(e.detail.newValue)) {
          // If the old value did have an 'a' and the new value doesn't, then decrement countOfA.
          this.countOfA--;
        }
        // Don't do anything for the other cases, since 'a'-ness has stayed the same.
      },

      handleListTap: function(e, _, el) {
        var item = el.templateInstance.model.item;

        if (this._hasA(item.text)) {
          item.text = item.text.slice(1);
        } else {
          item.text = 'a' + item.text;
        }
      },
      
      handleAddItem: function() {
        this.list.push({text: this.newItemText});
      },

      ready: function() {
        this.list = [
          {text: 'a'},
          {text: 'ab'},
          {text: 'ac'},
          {text: 'd'},
          {text: 'e'}
        ];
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<h1>Polymer Demo: Observing Changes to Properties of Items in an Array</h1>
<array-observation></array-observation>
```

I think it's a fairly idiomatic way of addressing what you're trying to do, in that it relies heavily on observation callbacks for ensuring that related state is kept up to date. You can directly modify your data from anywhere in your code without having to worry about forgetting to call a specific helper function, etc.